# Pulling Datetime when using COUNT(UserID)

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, count

I have the tables `Users`

```
UserID     FirstName     LastName     Email
------     ---------     --------     -----
1          Fred          Smith        fs@abc.com
2          Bob           Hill         bh@abc.com
3          Jane          Doe          jd@abc.com
```

and `LoginSession`

```
LoginSessionID     UserID     StartDate
--------------     ------     ---------
1                  1          2014-11-23 08:37:14.836
2                  1          2014-11-25 11:13:53.225
3                  2          2014-12-01 03:15:33.846
4                  1          2014-12-01 17:34:19.036
5                  3          2014-12-05 12:55:01.998
6                  1          2014-12-14 17:20:14.636
7                  3          2014-12-15 10:02:17.376
```

What I am trying to do is find the users who have logged on only once and find out when that was.

I have managed to find the users who have logged on only once by using

```
SELECT 
    U.FirstName, U.LastName, COUNT(L.UserID) AS Visits
FROM 
    LoginSession L
JOIN 
    Users U ON U.UserID = L.UserID
GROUP BY 
    U.FirstName, U.LastName
HAVING 
    COUNT(L.UserID) = 1
```

But I also want to pull through the `L.StartDate` of those users. If I add it to the select query I get an error because it's not contained in an aggregate function or `GROUP BY` clause. If I add it the the `GROUP BY` line (to avoid that error) I get each and every login handily marked as 1 visit!

I also tried using a subquery but I got an error because it returned more than one result.

I really am totally stumped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with aggregation:

```
select UserId, min(StartDate) as StartDate
from LoginSession ls
group by UserId
having count(*) = 1;
```

The `min()` returns the value you want, because there is only one row that matches.  You can use an addition `join` to get additional information about the users.

```
select u.*, lsu.StartDate
from Users u join
     (select UserId, min(StartDate) as StartDate
      from LoginSession ls
      group by UserId
      having count(*) = 1
     ) lsu
     on lsu.UserId = u.UserId;
```

Comment: Worked like a dream. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use windowed version of `COUNT`:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, StartDate
FROM (
  SELECT U.FirstName, U.LastName, L.StartDate,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY U.UserID) AS cnt
  FROM LoginSession L
  JOIN Users U ON U.UserID = L.UserID ) AS t
WHERE t.cnt = 1
```

`COUNT` with `OVER` clause will return the number of records per `U.UserID`. Using an outer query you can fetch exactly these records.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/aecee/1)

Comment: Also worked like a dream, thank you. And introduced me to 'PARTITION BY' which I didn't know about!